# ASP.Net Web Project vs Web Site

Tags: namespaces

I am working on two separate sites in ASP.Net C#.  One is a web project and one is a web site. I have a default page in the project, that works just fine, that I would like to copy to the web site.  The project default has a namespace in the code behind.  When I copy the code to the default of the web site, the code behind of the default page does not have a namespace and therefore the default page will not work in the web site. I have read a lot about the differences of project vs site, and namespace vs. no namespace, but I can find nothing about how I would get the default to work in the web site.  All the code is the same except for the namespace line in the code behind.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
enter code here


THE PAGE


   <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/DetailsOfRecipes.master"
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DetailsOfRecipes.aspx.cs"    Inherits="DetailsOfRecipes"   %>

   <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"   TagPrefix="asp" %>
   <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="Server">
   </asp:Content>
   <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
   <div id="masterLeftContainer">
            <asp:Image ID="Image7" runat="server" CssClass="leftContainerImage"    ImageUrl="~/Images/ketchup.png"
                AlternateText="cabo view" />
        </div>
        <div class="masterLeftMenuContainer">
            <div class="lowerLeftMenuContainer">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="masterContentContainer">
         <asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server">
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$  ConnectionStrings:RecipeUploadConnectionString %>"               
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server" />      
            <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" DataKeyNames="RecipeID"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
                runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="width: 500px">
                        <td rowspan="2">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="100px"  Height="80px" ImageUrl='<%# "~/Handler.ashx?RecipeID=" + Eval("RecipeID")%>' />
                        </td>
                        <td rowspan="2" width="100px">
                            <asp:Rating ID="Rating1" runat="server" align="right"  valign="top" CurrentRating='<%# Eval("RatingAVG")%>'
                                MaxRating="5" ReadOnly="true" StarCssClass="ratingStar"  WaitingStarCssClass="savedRatingStar"
                                FilledStarCssClass="filledRatingStar"  EmptyStarCssClass="emptyRatingStar">
                            </asp:Rating>
                            &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<br></br>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" align="right" Text='<%#  Eval("Count") %>' />&nbsp&nbsp
                            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Font-Size="12px"  ForeColor="Blue" Text="Reviews"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" ForeColor="Blue"    Width="275px" align="left"
                                NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("RecipeID",  "~/RecipeDetails.aspx?RecipeId={0}") %>' Text='<%# Eval("RecipeName") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                        </td>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="color: Purple">
                                <font color="red" size="2px">by:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</font>
                                <asp:Label ID="Name" runat="server" align="right"  Text='<%# Eval("YourName") %>' />&nbsp&nbsp
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="width: 500px">
                        <td colspan="5" style="color: Navy">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%#     Eval("Description") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <font color="#OOOOFF" size="2px">INGREDIENTS</font>
                        </td>

                </ItemTemplate>
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <table id="Table1" runat="server">
                        <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                            <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                                <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                                    <tr id="Tr2" runat="server" style="">
                                        <th id="Th1" runat="server">
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </LayoutTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
            </asp:Panel>         
              <asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Print"   OnClick="btnPrint_Click" /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnPrintCurrent" runat="server" Text="Print Current Page" OnClick =   "PrintCurrentPage" />
    </div>
    <div class="masterRightMenuContainer">
        </div>
        <div class="masterRightMenuContainer">
            <div class="lowerRightMenuContainer">
            </div>
            <div class="bottomRightMenuContainer">
            </div>
        </div>
     </asp:Content>

THE CODE BEHIND

   using System;
   using System.Data;
   using System.Data.SqlClient;
   using System.Configuration;
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Web;
   using System.Web.Security;
   using System.Web.UI;
   using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
   using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
   using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Web.SessionState;



    public partial class DetailsOfRecipes : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            BindGrid();
        }

        private void BindGrid()
        {
            string strQuery = "select * " + "from PostedRecipes";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
                          .ConnectionStrings["RecipeUploadConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                sda.Fill(dt);
                //ListView1.DataSource = dt;
                ListView1.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                sda.Dispose();
                con.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
        {
            /*Verifies that the control is rendered */
        }

        protected void OnPaging(object sender, PageEventArgs e)
        {

            ListView1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void PrintCurrentPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ListView1.DataBind();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            ListView1.RenderControl(hw);
            string gridHTML = sw.ToString().Replace("\"", "'")
                .Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
            sb.Append("window.onload = new function(){");
            sb.Append("var printWin = window.open('', '', 'left=0");
            sb.Append(",top=0,width=1000,height=600,status=0');");
            sb.Append("printWin.document.write(\"");
            sb.Append(gridHTML);
            sb.Append("\");");
            sb.Append("printWin.document.close();");
            sb.Append("printWin.focus();");
            sb.Append("printWin.print();");
            sb.Append("printWin.close();};");
            sb.Append("</script>");
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GridPrint", sb.ToString());

            ListView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the code? It probably has something to do with the .aspx file specifying the name of the class it references

Comment: AndrewK, all pertinent code has been add as an edit. I did remove Sql Code and some table trs to cut down on space.  This page is for printing recipes.  The page displays correctly in a browser, but when the print button is click, nothing happens.  It does work in the project.

Comment: Finally found the problem.  This page end result is to print the page. Although there is no mention in Microsoft literature that I have found, YOUR CANNOT PRINT ANYTHING in a straight fashion with Visual Studio Web Sites.  You can with Web Projects.  This is a Site.  It would seem that somewhere in their written comparisons of the Project vs Site that Microsoft would mention such a problem, but they don't appear to do so.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Sorry I didn't get back to this sooner.